# How to prevent Query of Queries returning case sensitive results from CFC in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-11, cfc, cfquery, qoq

I have an issue where I'm joining two record sets from two different datasources using Ben Nadel's QueryAppend.cfc. The data I get back is correct but the ordering of the data is not expected. The combined result set is being sorted like so with all results starting with a lowercase letter appended to the bottom of the record set:

[Screen grab of cfdump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xihhB.gif)

I'm expecting (and need) the following type of sort:

Apple

art

bottle

Boy

Cat

coin

dart

Dog

Code follows:

```
<!---Calling Template--->

<cfquery name="getDataSet1" datasource="datasource1">
SELECT param1
FROM table1
</cfquery> 

<cfquery name="getDataset2" datasource="datasource2">
 SELECT param1
FROM table2
</cfquery> 

<cfscript>
// Create object
 TheUnionObject = createObject("component", "cfc/QueryAppend");
 // Call the function
myUnionResult = TheUnionObject.QueryAppend(getDataSet1, getDataSet2);
</cfscript> 

<!---Dump results--->
<cfdump var="#myUnionResult#">






 <!---QueryAppend.cfc--->
 <cfcomponent>
 <cffunction name="QueryAppend" access="public" returntype="query" 
 output="false"
 hint="This takes two queries and appends the second one to the first one. 
  Returns the resultant third query.">
 <cfargument name="QueryOne" type="query" required="true" />
 <cfargument name="QueryTwo" type="query" required="true" />
 <cfset var LOCAL = StructNew() />
 <cfquery name="LOCAL.NewQuery" dbtype="query">
       (
            SELECT
               *
            FROM
                ARGUMENTS.QueryOne
        )
    UNION 
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                ARGUMENTS.QueryTwo
        )  ORDER BY Param1 ASC
  </cfquery>
 <cfreturn LOCAL.NewQuery />
  </cffunction>
  </cfcomponent>
```

I'm assuming that this default sorting behavior is some under-the-hood ColdFusion code. Can anyone tell me how to effect a change to this default ORDER BY behavior?

Comment: The queries are sorting correctly in that they are ASCII sorted. I think a quick fix would be to add a field to your select statement that uppercases (`ucase`) the field value you want to sort by and then order by that field, but still output the uncased field.

Comment: That was so simple I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it. Thanks for the clue.

Comment: Thanks! I'll post (a variation) of my comment as the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add a field to your select statement that upper cases ([upper](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html)) the field value you want to sort by and then order by that field, but still output the uncased field. Something along the lines of:

```
select   *, 
         upper(name) as upperName
from     query
order by upperName
```